# openproject, probleme in link generator for confirmation with email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openproject

i am using openproject on myserver on port `7000`, but when i send an email invitation for a user, it generates the activation url without the port my server is listening on for openproject,

https://myserver/account/activate?token=..

instead of

https://myserver:7000/account/activate?token=..

the link is generated in  `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb` using `url_for` function,

, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something like this in your application_controller.rb:

```
default_url_options[:port] = 7000 if Rails.env.production?
```

More info: [apidock/default_url_options](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options)

**Better way for action_mailer**

Using environments config as you've said in comments, like this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myserver', port: 7000 }
```

Comment: I added the port to the default options but nothing changed, here is the part you mentioned 

   'def default_url_options(_options = {})
    {
      layout: params['layout'],
      protocol: Setting.protocol
    }
  end
default_url_options[:port] = 7000'

Comment: @SlimaneAmiar you should put this to the application_controller, and set production env if your development env using port 3000.

Comment: thank you, i get it to work by adding 

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myserver', port: 7000 }


To config/environments/production.rb

you can edit your answer then i mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @SlimaneAmiar Yeah. Looks like it's better way if you need to set port only for mailer.